# Getting blank records in aws athena external table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Created one table using below code in AWS Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hourly_data_2 (
    data_col1 int,
    data_col2 int,
    data_col3 int,
    data_col4 timestamp
)
LOCATION "s3_path"
```

After creation, running simple `select * from hourly_data_2` query and it is giving me 2.11M records in output all with blank values.

[Image of query state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSghv.png)

Tried multiple time by dropping table still same issue. Want to create a blank table with 0 records.

Comment: If you want 0 records then the `s3_path` must point to an empty path in an S3 bucket.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the input data? What is the format of the files in that S3 location?

Comment: I have not inserted any data into table. And s3 location has csv, metadata and some folders in it.